# How to convert swf to swc?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

Am working on flash and Action Script.I want to convert my Shock wave flash to Shock wave component.how i can convert this?.Is there any possibility Please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: which IDE do you use?

Comment: Flash Develop@oto lolua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use flashDevelop it's easy you can download http://sourceforge.net/projects/exportswc/files/latest/download
this file and just drop in flashdevelop with drop... in menu bar appear icon and if you press this icon your output file will be swc

Comment: i did above steps.after i opened flash develop again am getting this Error  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at ExportSWC.PluginMain.HandleEvent(Object sender, NotifyEvent e, HandlingPriority prority)
   at PluginCore.Managers.EventManager.DispatchEvent(Object sender, NotifyEvent e) "